# Office ui fabric panel won't close

Tags: javascript, office-ui-fabric

I use an Office UI Fabric Panel (nothing special, just as in the Microsoft examples). However, I want to trigger the panel programmatically. I open the panel lik this:

```
 $("#btnOpenPanel").trigger( "click" );
```

In the panel I have a form. When I submit the form I do an update in the database and close the form. The database update works fine and I want to close the panel the same way I opened it. So like this again:

```
 $("#btnOpenAddPanel").trigger( "click" );
```

But that is not working. The panel remains open.

Is there some other way to close the panel?

Comment: Sorry to push but can someone help me out here?

Comment: At first glance I see that the selector isn't the same: the first time you select `#btnOpenPanel`, in the second selector there is an additional **Add** `#btnOpenAddPanel`. If that doesn't solve it, please post a more elaborate example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Using: panelInstance.dismiss(); closes the panel.